# Parse Json error, "Query failed: Input number: 688.43356 cannot round-trip through string representation"

Tags: json, google-cloud-spanner

Parse error of valid JSON, cannot round-trip through string representation"

The following query fails with "cannot roundtrip"

`

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"domInteractive_h": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {"n": 143, "mean": 688.43356, "max": 6000.0, "min": 76.0}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "domInteractive": {"n": 143, "mean": 688.43356, "max": 6000.0, "min": 76.0}} ') AS json_data;
```

`
While changing both numbers like this, does not fail

`

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"domInteractive_h": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {"n": 143, "mean": 1688.43356, "max": 6000.0, "min": 76.0}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "domInteractive": {"n": 143, "mean": 2688.43356, "max": 6000.0, "min": 76.0}} ') AS json_data;
```

`
The following solves it:

SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"domInteractive_h": [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {"n": 143, "mean": 688.43356, "max": 6000.0, "min": 76.0}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], "domInteractive": {"n": 143, "mean": 688.43356, "max": 6000.0, "min": 76.0}} ', wide_number_mode=>'round') AS json_data;
n
but not how to do this from python client?

Python solution, makes it better, but still error situations:

`

```
class RoundedFloat(float):
    @staticmethod
    def __repr__(num):
        return f'{num:.4f}'
​
​
json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None
json.encoder.float = RoundedFloat
```

`
Can't see that this is anything but a spanner problem. An object dumped with the above code must be a valid json object to put in a json column, or there must be some options on batch replace to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Spanner requires that floating point values can be roundtripped from string to double to string without precision loss. A possible workaround for this is to include the argument `wide_number_mode='round'` in your function call. Example:

```sql
PARSE_JSON('2.2412421353246235436', wide_number_mode=>'round')
```

See also the restrictions here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/working-with-json#specs

Comment: The correct syntax is:

`PARSE_JSON('2.2412421353246235436', wide_number_mode=>'round')`

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've updated the text accordingly.